# Case in Select Statement issue?

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I would normally use the popular if-else statement in java, but in sqlplus I'm using the case in select statement to query the conditional statement that I have here below.

```
 select title, to_char(nvl2(((retail-cost)/cost)*100, 
        ((retail-cost)/cost)*100, 
        ((retail-cost)/cost)*100), '99999.99') "Margin",
        to_char(discount, '99999.99') "Discount",
 (case when ("Margin" >= 60) then 'Very High Profit'
       when ("Margin" >= 30) then 'High Profit'
       else ("Margin" >= 0)  then 'Loss Leader' 
       end) "Pricing Structure"
    from books
    order by title;
```

I was hoping to get something like this as my result, but I tried to move the ordering; I'm still stuck with an error every time.

```
TITLE                          Margin   Discount  Pricing Structure
------------------------------ -------- --------- ---------------------------------
BIG BEAR AND LITTLE DOVE          68.23           Very high profit
BODYBUILD IN 10 MINUTES A DAY     65.07           Very high profit
```

Comment: This is the wrong way to go about it - hard to write, read and maintain. Instead, there should be a small table with the threshold for each "Pricing Structure" and its description; compute just the margin in your query and join to this small table. That way you can very easily add or delete levels, change the thresholds, and/or change the descriptions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sql can't see the alias unless it's in a subquery. You should write it something like:

```
case 
when (retail-cost/cost)*100 >= 60 then 'Very High Profit'
when (retail-cost/cost)*100 >= 30 then 'High Profit'
when  (retail-cost/cost)*100 >= 0  then 'Loss Leader' 
else 'SOMETHING HERE'
end "Pricing Structure"
```

Something else to consider is that this nvl2:

```
to_char(nvl2(((retail-cost)/cost)*100, 
    ((retail-cost)/cost)*100, 
    ((retail-cost)/cost)*100), '99999.99')
```

does nothing for you. Why? cause nvl2(exp1,exp2,exp3). If exp1 is not null then print exp2, when it is null then print exp3. Not only that but your NVL does nothing here cause it will always output ((retail-cost)/cost)*100. You're better off just writing `to_char(((retail-cost)/cost)*100),'99999.99')`.

If your exp1 = exp2 then you're better off just writing NVL(exp1,exp2). If exp1 is not null then it will print it, otherwise it will print exp2.

Comment: some of the values are null for the discount column, so if there is no discount at all; it would still calculate this ((retail-cost)/cost)*100 this one here.

Comment: I think you have me confused. The description I gave at the end was for the Margin calculation.

Comment: I'm sorry. Kindly ignore what my comment prior. I just remember the discount calculation is not included in the margin column. I'll try try to get around the part you've suggested where I don't have to use nvl2 and simply go straight to the calculation. I was too distracted in the case part that I forgot that little information hehe.

Comment: I appreciate the guide and thank you so much. It works!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the alias "Margin" in your case statement. You may use the whole formula of "Margin" in your case statement like:

(case (the NVL statement of Margin) > 60)

Also, make sure to match the same data types in your case statement. So, You cannot use to_char( ) > 60 since you are comparing a character to integer.

Hope this may help :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use a Common Table Expression (CTE) to factor out the calculation from the case logic:

```
WITH CDATA AS (select title,
                      ((retail-cost)/cost)*100 AS MARGIN,
                      to_char(discount, '99999.99') AS "Discount"
                 from books)
SELECT TITLE,
       TO_CHAR(MARGIN, '99999.99') AS "Margin",
       "Discount",
       case
         when MARGIN >= 60 then 'Very High Profit'
         when MARGIN >= 30 then 'High Profit'
         else MARGIN >= 0  then 'Loss Leader' 
       end AS "Pricing Structure"
  order by title;
```

Best of luck.